# Hibernate/JPA Mapping to a Base Class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, mapping

Considering the following entity. I intend to have the Child class reference any of the two derived food class ( Local Food or Foreign ). This is an contrived example, my real domain object are much complex, hence combining and using a FoodType column for example is not an option as both Food subclass are similar only in few traits.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Food {

}



@Entity
public class LocalFood extends Food {

private long id;
private String name;
}


@Entity
public class ForeignFood extends Food {

    private long id;
    private String name;
}



@Entity
public class Child {    
private Food food; //Base Class needed here 
@ManyToOne()
public Food getFood() {
    return food;
}
}

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on                     com.sample.Child.food references an unknown entity: com.sample.Food
```

Neither does using inheritance and discriminator.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Food {

private long id; // set , get (Auto gen) 
}
```

Is it possible to get this kind of mapping to work?

Comment: You must map the Food class as an entity, with an Inheritance strategy, for this to be possible. What is the exception you get when doing that?

Comment: I get  `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.JoinedSubclass`. For each InheritanceType.

Comment: This is caused by a mapping problem. See https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1005287 for example. This ID should be declared in the root class (Food). Not in every subclass.

Comment: True, subclasses should not have ID. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

JB Nizet was right. Now food class looks like this.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Food {

 private long id;

 public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 public long getId() {
    return id;
 }

}
```

And id removed from subclasses.